# htaccess to direct php file request only

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to set up my htaccess to redirect just my php file request only.  My htaccess file is set up like so:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks

RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /client

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !index\.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} \.php$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?request=$1 [L,QSA]
```

But a call to a php file via ajax does not redirect to the index.php.  What am I not doing correctly?  Thanks.

The URL begin sent is:

```
http://192.168.1.200/client/test.php?_dc=1438796049168&sr=ca8dfff9-e845-11e4-9d37-2637a38bcd64
```

Comment: Check in Chrome dev tool what full URL is being sent to server

Comment: Edited question to URL

Comment: maybe because in `.htaccess` it is `index.php` and your link is `test.php` ? I actually couldn't understand your question.

Comment: if I make a request to any php file, I want the php file to be redirected to a single php that will handle the request...bootstrapping my php.

Comment: so you want all files to redirect to `index.php` with that request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace your rule with this rule:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /client/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index\.php$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?\.php)$ index.php?request=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the `RewriteBase` line and the slash in front of `/index.php` and put it in a .htaccess file in your client folder, not in the parent folder (assuming that's the case currently).  I tested this and confirmed that appears to do what you're wanting it to do.  For example:

In /client/.htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !index\.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} \.php$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?request=$1 [L,QSA]
```